# Convert .pth Pytorch model to format readable by OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

I'm trying to use this model: https://github.com/zllrunning/face-makeup.PyTorch/blob/master/cp/79999_iter.pth with opencv dnn module but because opencv doesn't read .pth file, I need to convert it to another format.

First I tried to convert to .onnx, I found code to do it but when I call the function "torch.onnx.export", I got "RuntimeError: ONNX symbolic expected a constant value in the trace".
I tried with differrent version of torch but I always got almost the same error message.

I tried to convert to caffe model, there is some available github to do it but none of them worked for me.

I didn't find how to convert directly to tensorflow, they always convert to onnx and then to tensorflow.

If someone can share me a code that works for this model and the version of all packages used. Or if you could share me the model converted to another format, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? `pth` is a random extension, you can change it to anything you like. I doubt it its the extension opencv is complaining about.

Comment: This is all format that opencv can read: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#ga3b34fe7a29494a6a4295c169a7d32422 .pth is a pytorch format that opencv doesn't read.

Comment: OK, I see. now could you please tell us how you tried to convert the model into the onnx and how it failed? what kind of errors did you get?